# android studio: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5 while adding facebook login button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

It's been two days that i am getting this problem whenever i try adding a facebook login button in android studio.

**MainActivity.java**
 package org.example.rahul_a.firstapp;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private SignInButton gbutton;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions;
    public String userName;
    private TextView t1;
    private Button b1;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions).build();
        gbutton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.gbutton);

        gbutton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        gbutton.setScopes(signInOptions.getScopeArray());
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        gbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

        userName = account.getDisplayName();
        t1.setText("Welcome " + userName);

    }

}



@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.rahul_a.firstapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LOGCAT DUMP**

```
03-29 22:36:10.036 30427-30427/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-29 22:36:10.136 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
03-29 22:36:10.136 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 574: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
03-29 22:36:10.136 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
03-29 22:36:10.166 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
03-29 22:36:10.166 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
03-29 22:36:10.176 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
03-29 22:36:10.176 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19943: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19947: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30427/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
03-29 22:36:10.196 30427-30458/org.example.rahul_a.firstapp E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 653: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 675: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-29 22:36:10.236 30427-30427/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.266 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not all deps represented
03-29 22:36:10.266 30427-30427/? E/dalvikvm: /system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar odex has stale dependencies
03-29 22:36:10.266 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: not all deps represented
03-29 22:36:10.266 30427-30427/? E/dalvikvm: /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar odex has stale dependencies
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 616: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 618: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-29 22:36:10.296 30427-30427/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-29 22:36:10.366 30427-30472/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
03-29 22:36:10.366 30427-30472/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 261: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
03-29 22:36:10.366 30427-30472/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
03-29 22:36:10.406 30427-30427/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1__release_AU ()
                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
                                               Build Date: 08/06/14 Wed
                                               Local Branch: mybranch4057433
                                               Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_rb1
                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                               Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004 +  NOTHING
03-29 22:36:10.436 30427-30427/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-29 22:36:10.446 30427-30475/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41da6d58)
03-29 22:36:10.446 30427-30475/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                                   Process: org.example.rahul_a.firstapp, PID: 30427
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
                                                       at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:823)
                                                       at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-29 22:36:10.456 30427-30475/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30427 SIG: 9
```

All this was working without facebook login button.

Comment: Refer here you will figure out your problem its http://coderzpassion.com/android-using-facebook-login-application-using-latest-facebook-sdk/

Comment: @JagjitSingh Tried it but still not working.

Comment: put meta data tag inside application tag

Comment: @JagjitSingh OMG! ITS WORKING NOW! THANKS.